# MySQL 5.7.22: How to SELECT JSON value when it's key contains dot character?

Tags: mysql, json, select

So, the JSON structure looks like that:

```
{
  "pixel.uuid": "1ca86b7d7505c48363b2a5d9dde0c7e4",
  "innerWidth": "1440"
}
```

Question: How do I select "pixel.uuid"? I tried these combinations:

```
select json->"$.pixel.uuid" from TrackingData_experimental
```

```
select json->"$.pixel\.uuid" from TrackingData_experimental
```

```
select json->{"$.pixel.uuid"} from TrackingData_experimental
```

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.pixel.uuid') from TrackingData_experimental
```

But with no luck.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delimit the key in double-quotes:

```
mysql> select json->'$."pixel.uuid"' from TrackingData_experimental;
+------------------------------------+
| json->'$."pixel.uuid"'             |
+------------------------------------+
| "1ca86b7d7505c48363b2a5d9dde0c7e4" |
+------------------------------------+
```

If you want the value returned unquoted, do this:

```
mysql> select json->>'$."pixel.uuid"' from TrackingData_experimental;
+----------------------------------+
| json->>'$."pixel.uuid"'          |
+----------------------------------+
| 1ca86b7d7505c48363b2a5d9dde0c7e4 |
+----------------------------------+
```